# Maximum number of members in IBMi PF and maximum number of records in a member

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I have a task that requires potentially adding a very large number of members to a multimember physical file.

I do a DSPFD on the file and I see below under database file attributes:

Maximum members . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : MAXMBRS    *NOMAX

Does it mean there is no limit to the number of members that could be added to this PF ?

I also want to know if there is any limit on the number of records that could be added to the individual member. Would there be any limit on the total of all records in all members ?

Comment: You might just refer to this link "https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=concepts-database-file-sizes".

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=concepts-database-file-sizes) for v7.5 which is the most recent...

```
- Number of records contained in a file member . . . 4,294,967,288 records 
- Number of bytes in a file member . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1.7 terabytes  
- Maximum number of members in a physical or logical file  . 32,767
```

So conceivably, you could have a single 55.7 Petabyte file.

Note that the number of bytes limit footnote

> This limit is the size of the internal data space, not the size of the
> entire object. This size will vary based on the field types of the
> file. Both the number of bytes in a file member and the number of
> bytes in an access path must be looked at when message CPF5272 is sent
> indicating that the maximum system object size has been reached.